# Unescaping bash characters with Python

Tags: python-3.x, bash, escaping

I have a bash-runnable string in Python containing

```
export MY_PASSWORD="pass\$word"
```

where \$ stands for the escaped character.

I'd like to set this variable in my Python session using

```
os.environ["MY_PASSWORD"]="pass$word"
```

For example, I could do this for this case via

```
myStr.replace('\\$','$')
```

But this is not generic -- what is a generic way to perform the necessary conversion and un-escape all escaped Bash chars?

Comment: The "generic" way essentially requires a full-blown `bash`-to-Python compiler, since the value being assigned could be an arbitrary `bash` script. (Think `export MY_PASSWORD=$(...)`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of double quoting use single quoting in bash.

```
export MY_PASSWORD='pass$word'
```

This way you circumvent the problem in its totality.

"Un-escaping escaped bash chars in Python" sounds like asking for big problems.

Comment: hah brilliant, I just learned something new about bash, thank you :)

Comment: @GordonDavisson A more similar way between bash and python of escaping such characters is the use ANSI-C quoting: `$'..'`